# Jasmine incorrectly marking spec as pending

Tags: javascript, jasmine

[Jasmine](https://jasmine.github.io/) is marking my spec as pending when it has not been prepended with an `x`.

Here is the code:

```
it('some spec description'), () => {
  expect(true).toBe(true)
}
```

[image: The spec in the Jasmine GUI:]

This took me a while to figure out, but thought it may be useful in case anyone was having the same problem. Answer below.

Comment: This is just a typo, and has nothing to do with Jasmine per se. It could happen with any function that accepts callbacks.

Comment: Completely agree, but my initial problem lead me specifically to ask this question of Stack Overflow in this context, assuming that it would be a Jasmine issue. Thought it would be a good catch for someone wondering the same thing and save them some time. The resulting typo still registers the jasmine spec, but marks it as pending, leading to some confusion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So there is a not-so-obvious typing error here, a closing parenthesis in the wrong place, which does not get picked up by the linter or compiler.

The code effectively runs this:

```
it('some spec description')

() => {
  expect(true).toBe(true)
}
```

Technically valid code, but not what was intended. This is the fix:

```
it('some spec description', () => {
  expect(true).toBe(true)
})
```

Note the moving of closing parenthesis for the `it()` method to the end of the block.